# scraping dynamic website using scrapy playwrright

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape javascript website using `scrapy-playwright` but they show  `Crawled 0 pages` is there any mistake I have done in code that why they are not crawling any data these is the page link https://www.coursera.org/search?query=python&utm_source=gg&utm_medium=sem&utm_campaign=B2C_INDIA__branded_FTCOF_courseraplus_arte_monthly&utm_content=B2C&campaignid=18216928761&adgroupid=141296026472&device=c&keyword=coursera%20online&matchtype=b&network=g&devicemodel=&adpostion=&creativeid=619458216863&gclid=CjwKCAiAkfucBhBBEiwAFjbkr5EhIFModjG1bK9jcqv126-AOgp4M-DzZCXXwLJyy_e16UZkmoUuxRoC_IcQAvD_BwE

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sample'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(

            url="https://www.coursera.org/search?query=python&utm_source=gg&utm_medium=sem&utm_campaign=B2C_INDIA__branded_FTCOF_courseraplus_arte_monthly&utm_content=B2C&campaignid=18216928761&adgroupid=141296026472&device=c&keyword=coursera%20online&matchtype=b&network=g&devicemodel=&adpostion=&creativeid=619458216863&gclid=CjwKCAiAkfucBhBBEiwAFjbkr5EhIFModjG1bK9jcqv126-AOgp4M-DzZCXXwLJyy_e16UZkmoUuxRoC_IcQAvD_BwE",
            callback=self.parse,
            meta={
                "playwright": True,
                "playwright_page_methods": [
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "ul.cds-71"),
                ],
            },
        )
   
        
    def parse(self, response):
        yield{
            'text':response.text
        }
```

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: working on 64 bit operating system...

Comment: is playwright is not supporting on my operating system?

Comment: you run these code they give you an output.......

Comment: scrapy playwright doesn't work on windows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, you can not directly use playwright. To use it, you have to set up WSL on your windows to run the playwright.
You can check this

https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright/issues/7

To know how to launch the browser using WSL,
https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright/issues/78